# Is there a way to make a query that looks in serialized binary object in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: c#, sql-server, serialization, deserialization

I have an object called Data serialized as varbinary(MAX). Data object contains property named Source. Is there a way to make something similar:

```
select * from content_table where Data.Source == 'Feed'
```

I know that it is possible when XML serialization is used (XQuery). But serialization type cannot be changed in this case.

Answer (score 3):

If you have used `BinaryFormatter`, then no, not really - at least, not without deserilizing the entire object model, which is usually not possible at the database. It is an undocumented format, with very little provision for ad-hoc query.

Note: `BinaryFormatter` is not (IMO) a good choice for anything that relates to *storage* of items; I fully expect that this ***will*** bite you at some point (i.e. unable to reliably deserialize the data you have stored). Pain points:

- tightly tied to type names; can break as you move code around
- tightly tied to field names; can break as you refactor your classes (even just creating to an automatically implemented property is a breaking change)
- prone to including a bigger graph than you expect, in particular via events

It is of course also platform-specific, and *potentially* framework-specific.

In all seriousness, I've lost count of the number of "I can't deserialize my data" questions I've fielded over the years...

There are *alternative binary serializers* that *do* allow some (limited) ability to inspect the data via a reader (without requiring full deserialization), and which *do not* become tied to the type metadata (instead, being contract-based, allowing deserialization into any suitable type model - not just that *specific* type/version.

**However**, I genuinely doubt that such work work with anything approaching efficiency in a `WHERE` clause etc; you would need a SQL/CLR method etc. IMO, a better approach here is simply to store the required *filter* columns as data in other columns, allowing you to add indexing etc. On the rare occasions that I have used the `xml` type, this is the same as I have done *there* (with the small caveat that you can use "lifted" computed+stored+indexed columns from the underlying xml data, which wouldn't be possible here - the extra columns would have to be explicit).

Answer (score 0):

You could deserialise the data, using a [SQL CLR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189876.aspx) function. But I suspect it wont be fast. It all depends on how the serialisation was done. If the library is available, then a simple CLR function, shuld be able to query the data quite easily.